# tab bar project with login screen

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

I am creating a tab bar controller project but also want to have a login screen before showing this. i also want a settings screen and info screen to be available to view from the login screen. if login is successful, then show the tab bar view. also to log out from the tab bar view.

what is the best way of doing this? what type of project and how to do the login screen?

any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all create the viewbased project.In the first viewcontroller add the login screen.After that in loginscreenxib create the object of tabbarcontroller.